# Choosing an object randomly from a List in java

Tags: java, list, object, random

Before you start giving -1 to this question, I wanna say that I have already read at least 4 questions about this kind of problem, but each of them didn't help me completely.

I have this class which contains the following method:

```
class OperationDispatcher {

    OperationDispatcher(ManagementService.Client managementClient) {
        this.managementClient = managementClient;
    }

    ManagementService.Client managementClient;

    public long executeOperation(String opName, int num1, int num2) throws TException {

        List<ServiceProvider> providers = new ArrayList<ServiceProvider>();
        providers = managementClient.getProvidersForService(opName);

        long result = 0;

        if(providers.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("No Service Available");
        else
            switch(opName) {
                case "addition":
                    result = arithmeticClient.add(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "multiplication":
                    result = arithmeticClient.multiply(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "substraction":
                    result = arithmeticClient.substract(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "division":
                    result = arithmeticClient.divide(num1, num2);
                    break;  
        }   
        return result;
    }

}
```

Iìm trying to achieve this behaviour:

1. two or more objects "Node" register to a local central server i create in my test;
2. each Node has a list of Services and makes requests to OR provides services for other Nodes;
3. when a request is made, a List of "ServiceProviders" is returned, each one of them being a possible "answering node";
4. A random ServiceProvider is chosen from the list;
5. the chosen ServiceProvider executes the arithmetic operation requested.

I have no issues with points 1, 2, 3 and 5. I'm now trying to modify the method to make it choose a random ServiceProvider among the ones present in the list.

I'm not sure about where (in my class) should I put the code for random picking the object from the list and making it then execute the operation requested. Can you help me?

EDIT so, I have modified my code as follows:

```
class OperationDispatcher {

    private List<ServiceProvider> providers = new ArrayList<ServiceProvider>();

    OperationDispatcher(ManagementService.Client managementClient) {
        this.managementClient = managementClient;
    }

    //tiro su un management client
    ManagementService.Client managementClient;

    public long executeOperation(String opName, int num1, int num2) throws TException {

        ServiceProvider randomProvider = new ServiceProvider();
        providers = managementClient.getProvidersForService(opName);

        long result = 0;

        if(providers.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("No Service Available");

        else if(providers.size() == 1) {
            switch(opName) {
                case "addition":
                    result = arithmeticClient.add(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "multiplication":
                    result = arithmeticClient.multiply(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "substraction":
                    result = arithmeticClient.substract(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "division":
                    result = arithmeticClient.divide(num1, num2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        else if (providers.size() >= 2) {
            randomProvider = providers.get(random.nextInt(providers.size()));
            if(randomProvider != null) {
                switch(opName) {
                case "addition":
                    result = arithmeticClient.add(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "multiplication":
                    result = arithmeticClient.multiply(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "substraction":
                    result = arithmeticClient.substract(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "division":
                    result = arithmeticClient.divide(num1, num2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

My test is this:

```
@Before
public void initializeManagementServer() throws Exception {

    managementServer = new ManagementServer(7911);
    managementServer.start();

    Thread.sleep(200);
    managementServerTransport = new TSocket("localhost", 7911);
    managementServerProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(managementServerTransport);
    managementClient = new ManagementService.Client(managementServerProtocol);
    managementServerTransport.open();
}

@Test
public void testArithmeticServer() throws Exception {

    ServiceProvider randomProvider = new ServiceProvider();

    List<String> node1Svc = new ArrayList<>();
    node1Svc.add("addition");

    List<String> node2Svc = new ArrayList<>();
    node2Svc.add("substraction");
    node2Svc.add("multiplication");

    List<String> node3Svc = new ArrayList<>();
    node3Svc.add("addition");
    node3Svc.add("multiplication");
    node3Svc.add("division");

    List<String> node4Svc = new ArrayList<>();
    node4Svc.add("addition");
    node4Svc.add("division");

    NodeManifest node1 = new NodeManifest("Node 1", node1Svc);
    NodeManifest node2 = new NodeManifest("Node 2", node2Svc);
    NodeManifest node3 = new NodeManifest("Node 3", node3Svc);
    NodeManifest node4 = new NodeManifest("Node 4", node4Svc);

    int port = managementClient.registerNode(node1);
    assertEquals(1026, port);
    port = managementClient.registerNode(node2);
    assertEquals(1027, port);
    port = managementClient.registerNode(node3);
    assertEquals(1028, port);
    port = managementClient.registerNode(node4);
    assertEquals(1029, port);



    arithmeticServer = new ArithmeticServer(port);
    arithmeticServer.start();

    arithmeticTransport = new TSocket("localhost", port);
    arithmeticProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(arithmeticTransport);
    arithmeticClient = new ArithmeticService.Client(arithmeticProtocol);
    arithmeticTransport.open();

    OperationDispatcher dispatcher = new OperationDispatcher(managementClient);
    long result = dispatcher.executeOperation("addition", 1, 2);
    assertEquals(3, result);
    assertEquals(3, dispatcher.providers.size());

    arithmeticTransport.close();
    arithmeticServer.stop();

@After
public void teardownManagementServer() throws Exception {
    managementServerTransport.close();
    managementServer.stop();            
}
}
```

I have registered 4 nodes. Node #1 is the one asking for the service "addition", node #2 #3 and #4 all have that service. Then I create an object OperationDispatcher asking for the service "addition", and it returns a list containing three ServiceProviders. Now I want to choose one item at random from that list and finally that ServiceProvider executes the operation. Right now, node 4 is always chosen instead. What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you assign `providers` to a `new ArrayList` and then immediately to something else?

Comment: And what's the point of choosing a provider from the list, since the code doesn't use it? All it does is calling arithmeticClient.

Comment: each node can be either a serviceProvider or an arithmeticClient. If it provides a service, it acts as server and executes the operation, if it asks for a service it acts as client and asks for an operation to be executed.

Comment: in the state above your code won't even compile and you have a switch inside an else block of it thats strange

Comment: do I have to add all code i've written in test? It's pretty long..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java's [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class as follows:

```
ServiceProvider provider = providers.get(new Random().nextInt(providers.size()));
```

Note that initializing new `Random` objects is a slightly expensive operation, so you probably want to create it once, and then keep reusing it:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

// ...

ServiceProvider provider = providers.get(RANDOM.nextInt(providers.size()));
```

Comment: Ok, I have an object ServiceProvider named provider, randomly chosen. Now I don't understand how to use it into executeOperation() and make it execute the operation requested...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a `List` of services as `servicesList`
now do as follows:

```
double ramdomVal = Math.random();
int size =servicesList.size();

int pos = (new Double(ramdomVal %size)).intValue();

Service service = servicesList.get(pos);
```

This way you will always get a random service object.

Comment: I would love to know the reason for down votes, I have tested the solution I provided and worked fine.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the formatting certainly deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

just another thought coming to my mind. If you can use Collections api `shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)`
,chances of getting distinct values may increase.
Refer docs for further details :
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29)